# Render R Markdown HTML file inside a function issue

Tags: sql, r, function, r-markdown, odbc

I am working through an ODBC connection to a SQL server to query data and build reports. Right now I have a script that works exactly as it should to render the .Rmd files and place it in the folder, but I'm working on a more streamlined way to do it through a function instead.

The basis of the function goes as followed:

```
RenderFxn = function(RMDfile, OutputName){

source = "path/to/scripts/"
output = "path/to/output/location/"

rmarkdown::render(input = paste0(source,RMDfile,".Rmd"),
                  output_file = paste0(output,OutputName,"_",DATE))

}

RenderFxn("CreateReport","ReportOutput")
```

It works if I go line by line, but as soon as I call it through the function I get an error. The error occurs at the first chunk of code that connects to the SQL server through the ODBC connection. But again, it works fine if i don't call it through a function.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here, I'm inferring most of them lacking code. Here's a stab:

1. `DATE` is undefined, error.
2. I am going to *guess* that the Rmarkdown document is unable to query the data you need. Note that the rendering process is in a clean environment, so if you have objects such as `conn`, `mydata`, `param1`, and yes, even `DATE` in the *global* (calling) environment, you need to pass almost all of them via the `render(.., params=list(...))` argument. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html.

   The notable exception to that is that `conn` (whether from `DBI::dbConnect` or `RODBC::` something) cannot be passed here, as well as similar objects that contain a memory `<pointer>`. To fix this, you'll need to pass the parameters you passed to `DBI::dbConnect` and *recreate the connection object inside of the Rmarkdown document*.
3. (minor) Use `file.path` instead of `paste0` when forming the directory components of a path, it's far less likely that you'll forget the trailing slash.
4. Your function should accept more arguments, since it is breaking scope and trying to find things it has no guarantee of finding. In general, functions should be explicitly passed what it needs. There are obviously exceptions to this, but without explicit arguments, your function is not strictly reproducible, troubleshooting it is a pain, and other users/readers have no clue what is required, what should be found, what they should look like, etc. (By "users", I'm including *you* in six months after you've forgotten the details.)

   I suggest a function like this:

   ```r
   RenderFunc <- function(rmd, outputname, ...,
                          date = Sys.Date(),
                          source = "path/to/scripts/",
                          outputpath = "path/to/output/location/") {
     params <- c(list(...), date = date)
     if (!endsWith(rmd, ".Rmd")) rmd <- paste0(rmd, ".Rmd")
     outputname <- paste(OutputName, date, sep = "_")
     rmarkdown::render(input = file.path(source, rmd),
                       output_file = file.path(output, outputname),
                       params = params)
   }
   RenderFunc("CreateReport", "ReportOutput", data=mydata,
              dbuser="myuser", dbpass="mypass", dbhost="somehost")
   ```

   where in this case, `data=` is a parameter defined in the rmarkdown document, and the `db*` variables will be passed within the `list(...)` part of `params` so that the Rmd can instantiate the connection.

A living/breathing example of the target Rmarkdown document:

````
---
title: My Document
output: html_document
params:
  date: !r Sys.Date()
  data:
  dbuser:
  dbpass:
  dbhost:
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(DBI)
conn <- dbConnect(uid = params$dbuser, pwd = params$dbpass, server = params$server)
```

# Some Header

```{r block1}
remotedata <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select ...")
# do something here
```
````

In this example, I'm assuming you are passing `data=` (some form of frame, perhaps) as well as querying from the database. Whichever you want is up to you.

I'm generally not a fan of putting DBI code in the rmarkdown document; it works and there are many use-cases when it makes absolute sense, but sometimes it can be much simpler for the Rmd to *just* deal with data, not with connections and queries and such. For this, you might modify the func to be:

```r
RenderFunc2 <- function(rmd, outputname, ...,
                        dbuser, dbpass, dbhost,
                        date = Sys.Date(),
                        source = "path/to/scripts/",
                        outputpath = "path/to/output/location/") {
  params <- c(list(...), date = date)
  if (!endsWith(rmd, ".Rmd")) rmd <- paste0(rmd, ".Rmd")
  outputname <- paste(OutputName, date, sep = "_")
  conn <- DBI::dbConnect(uid=dbuser, pwd=dbpass, server=dbhost)
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn))
  mydata <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select ...")
  params$data <- mydata
  rmarkdown::render(input = file.path(source, rmd),
                    output_file = file.path(output, outputname),
                    params = params)
}
RenderFunc("CreateReport", "ReportOutput", data=mylocaldata,
           dbuser="myuser", dbpass="mypass", dbhost="somehost")
```

In this case, the `db*` arguments are used solely by `RenderFunc` and not passed to the Rmd document (which would *not* be trying to create a db connection).

Answer (score 0):

@r2evans answer clearly answers the question; +1 for the suggestion of not putting DBI code in Rmd.

This is to suggest that future readers might like to look at the [sqlhelper package](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper/), which I wrote specifically to facilitate this kind of integration. A third version of the render function that uses it might look like:

```
RenderFunc3 <- function(rmd, outputname, ...,
                    dbuser, dbpass, dbhost,
                    date = Sys.Date(),
                    source = "path/to/scripts/",
                    outputpath = "path/to/output/location/") {

params <- c(list(...), date = date)

if (!endsWith(rmd, ".Rmd")) rmd <- paste0(rmd, ".Rmd")

outputname <- paste(OutputName, date, sep = "_")

mydata <- sqlhelper::run_files("path_to_sql_file.SQL")

params$data1 <- mydata$query1
params$data2 <- mydata$query2

rmarkdown::render(input = file.path(source, rmd),
                  output_file = file.path(output, outputname),
                  params = params)
}

RenderFunc3("CreateReport", "ReportOutput", data=mylocaldata,
           dbuser="myuser", dbpass="mypass", dbhost="somehost")
```

(this example makes some assumptions about how you have specified your connections; there are several examples in the sqlhelper documentation)